# Derivative of tan(x)

Tags: derivatives

One can use the fact that $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ to derive the derivative of $\tan(x)$.
$(\tan(x))'=1+\tan^2(x)$

How can I show that $ (\tan(x))'=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$ ? 
Is there a link/connection to the definition(s) mentioned in the first paragraph?

Comment: hint: use the quotient rule and a basic trig identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know $\tan'(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$ you can do "common denominator":
$$
1+\tan^2(x) = 1+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}
=\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}
$$